# How did Albus and Scorpius end up in 1981 and how did they stay there for such a long time?

Tags: harry-potter, the-cursed-child

In *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child* act 3 part 19 Albus, Scorpius and Delphi go back in time to 1995 using the "prototype" Time Turner that only works for 5 minutes. A bit later the Time Turner gets destroyed.

However in Act 4, Scene 2 they are in 1981. **How did they get there without a proper time turner, and how are they able to remain there for so long?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**When they fought over the Time Turner it seems to have landed them all in 1981.**

> **SCORPIUS:** *The Time-Turner is spinning . . . Look at what she’s doing . . . She can’t leave us behind.*
>
> ALBUS and SCORPIUS both scramble to grab part of the Time-Turner.
> And there is a giant whoosh of light. A smash of noise.
> And time stops. And then it turns over, thinks a bit, and begins spooling backwards, slow at first . . 
> And then it speeds up.

**When Delphi smashed the Time Turner it stranded them there. The five minute rule no longer applies.**

> **SCORPIUS:** *Albus . . .*
>
> **ALBUS:** *What have we done?*
>
> **SCORPIUS:** *We had to go with the Time-Turner, we had to try to stop her.*
>
> **DELPHI:** *Stop me? How do you think you’ve stopped me? I am done with this. You may have destroyed my chances of using Cedric to darken
> the world but maybe you’re right, Scorpius — maybe prophecies can be
> prevented, maybe prophecies can be broken. What is undoubtedly true
> is: I’m done with trying to use you annoying, incompetent creatures
> for anything. No more wasting precious seconds on either of you. Time
> to try something new.*
>
> She crushes the Time-Turner. It explodes in a thousand pieces.
>
> DELPHI ascends again into the air. She laughs in delight as she sets
> off hard away.
>
> The boys try to chase her, but they’ve not the slightest chance. She
> flies, they run.
>
> **ALBUS:** *No . . . No . . . You can’t . . .*
>
> SCORPIUS turns back and tries to pick up the Time-Turner pieces.
>
> *The Time-Turner? It’s destroyed?*
>
> **SCORPIUS:** *Utterly. We’re stuck here. In time. **Wherever in time we are.** Whatever it is she’s planning to do.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Cursed Child - Act 3, Scene 20](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Harry-Potter-Cursed-Child-Production/dp/0751565350)</sup></sub>

Comment: Aaah ... thanks. I just missed the "begins spooling backwards". For me it looked like the Time turner just returned them back as it did in the other two cases.